# Process.Start - struggling with arguments to TFS command line

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm trying to execute TFS via Process.Start but am having some difficulty and I can't understand why. Here's my code snippet:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the entire history for a project
        /// </summary>
        public void GetHistory(String project)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            String fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            info.Arguments = String.Format("history \"{0}\" /recursive /format:Detailed /noprompt > {1}", "c:\\source\\ " + project, fileName);
            info.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe\"";
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = info;
            process.Start();

            process.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine("History written to " + fileName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

This is resulting in a set of arguments like so (I've just removed the full project name):

[image]

I then get the following error:

> The history command takes exactly one item.

If I piece the string together and execute in a normal command line however then it works:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect output to a file in the `Process.Start` arguments.  File redirection is a function of the shell.

If you want to put the history into a file, you will need to `File.Open` the file yourself, read the output of the `tf history` command and write it to the file.

Or you could use a command script or PowerShell script.